# Lag/buffer when playing video from network using video_player plugin flutter supabase

Tags: flutter, cloudflare, supabase

The code:

```
final VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController =
      VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
    Uri.parse('URL FROM SUPABASE STORAGE'),
  );

videoPlayerController.initialize();
videoPlayerController.setVolume(1);
videoPlayerController.setLooping(true);
videoPlayerController.play();
```

Code above can play the video, but the problems are:

1. There is a seconds of loading before the video shows and plays. I think its because the video size is big (28 mb) so need a time to fetch from supabase storage.
2. When the video is playing, sometime there is a buffer, always twice times. It happens along the video of each looping.

I analyze maybe because the server is too far from my place when i request it. But supabase already use CDN (cloudflare). So, i think the distance is not one of the problems.

Comment: Videos are a complicated data to handle, and there are many parameters that could affect how quick a video can load. Here is something that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816106/fast-encoding-video-codec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't about supabase server, device, or internet speed, but the problem come from the "video".

I change the bitrate of video to more lower using ffmpeg and it works.

> when converting a video for online streaming, a lower bitrate may help reduce load times.